# Page for page redirect in Google App Engine

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, google-app-engine, python

I have recently changed domain name for a webapp I run on Google App Engine and I am wondering if there is a simple way to do a page for page redirect from my old website to the new domain.  Everything code wise is staying exactly the same but I just want it to go to the new domain.

I am using Python and the webapp2 framework for the web app.

I know I could go through and for every single handler do:

```
webapp2.redirect('the specific url', permanent=True)
```

but I am hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this on a global scale using  webapp.RequestHandlers

```
class FormHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        if processFormData(self.request):
            self.redirect("the specific url")
        else:
```

Also this your find more support on stack overflow since this is python based coding.